# I saved my data wrong in Excel

Tags: excel, act, sage-erp

I use Excel as a large database. Basically, I saved my ACT! by Sage database to Excel to protect it while fixing my  computer and haven't updated a new copy of ACT! yet.  In the mean time, I need to work from the Excel file. It worked just fine yesterday, but today when I went back in, all the data was appearing in one cell.

> events                        piece of cake wedding design            10/13/2011
>   0:32  x   10/11/2012
>   10:18 glenda.apieceofcake@gmail.com                                                               cocktails   10/11/2012
>   10:18                                                             0   cocktails   cocktails                                                               www.apieceofcakeweddingdesign.com

All those are appearing in Cell A, there must be some formatting still when I cut and Paste as they separated.

Comment: This isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data into a text file.  Then, use Text Import in Excel, and set the delimiter to be a space.  I think that will work for you.